# How to suppress third party logs in pytest

Tags: python, logging, pytest, nose

We've just switched from `nose` to `pytest` and there doesn't seem to be an option to suppress third party logging. In `nose` config, we had the following line:

```
logging-filter=-matplotlib,-chardet.charsetprober,-PIL,-fiona.env,-fiona._env
```

Some of those logs are very chatty, especially `matplotlib` and we don't want to see the output, just output from our logs.

I can't find an equivalent setting in `pytest` though. Is it possible? Am I missing something? Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

The way I do it is by creating a list of logger names for which logs have to be disabled in **conftest.py**.

For example, if I want to disable a logger called `app`, then I can write a **conftest.py** as below:

```
import logging

disable_loggers = ['app']

def pytest_configure():
    for logger_name in disable_loggers:
        logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
        logger.disabled = True
```

And then run my test:

```
import logging

def test_brake():
    logger = logging.getLogger("app")
    logger.error("Hello there")
    assert True
```

> collecting ... collected 1 item
>
> test_car.py::test_brake PASSED
> [100%]
>
> ============================== 1 passed in 0.01s ===============================

Then, **Hello there** is not there because the logger with the name `app` was disabled in **conftest.py**.

However, if I change my logger name in the test to `app2` and run the test again:

```
import logging

def test_brake():
    logger = logging.getLogger("app2")
    logger.error("Hello there")
    assert True
```

> collecting ... collected 1 item
>
> test_car.py::test_brake
> -------------------------------- live log call --------------------------------- ERROR    app2:test_car.py:5 **Hello there** PASSED
> [100%]
>
> ============================== 1 passed in 0.01s ===============================

As you can see, **Hello there** is in because a logger with `app2` is not disabled.

## Conclusion

Basically, you could do the same, but just add your undesired logger names to **conftest.py** as below:

```
import logging

disable_loggers = ['matplotlib', 'chardet.charsetprober', <add more yourself>]

def pytest_configure():
    for logger_name in disable_loggers:
        logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
        logger.disabled = True
```

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the ability to tune logging levels or not show any log output at all which I'm sure [you've read in the docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/logging.html), the only way that comes to mind is to configure your logging in general.

Assuming that all of those packages use the standard library logging facilities, you have various options of configuring what gets logged. Please take a look at the [advanced tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging) for a good overview of your options.

If you don't want to configure logging for your application in general but only during testing, you might do so using the [pytest_configure](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_configure) or [pytest_sessionstart](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_sessionstart) hooks which you might place in a `conftest.py` at the root of your test file hierarchy.

Then I see three options:

1. The brute force way is to use the default behaviour of `fileConfig` or `dictConfig` to disable all existing loggers. In your `conftest.py`:

   ```py
   import logging.config


   def pytest_sessionstart():
       # This is the default so an empty dictionary should work, too.
       logging.config.dictConfig({'disable_existing_loggers': True})
   ```
2. The more subtle approach is to change the level of individual loggers or disable them. As an example:

   ```py
   import logging.config


   def pytest_sessionstart():
       logging.config.dictConfig({
           'disable_existing_loggers': False,
           'loggers': {
               # Add any noisy loggers here with a higher loglevel.
               'matplotlib': {'level': 'ERROR'}
           }
       })
   ```
3. Lastly, you can use the [pytest_addoption](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_addoption) hook to add a command line option similar to the one you mention. Again, at the root of your test hierarchy put the following in a `conftest.py`:

   ```py
   def pytest_addoption(parser):
       parser.addoption(
           "--logging-filter",
           help="Provide a comma-separated list of logger names that will be "
           "disabled."
       )


   def pytest_sessionstart(pytestconfig):
       for logger_name in pytestconfig.getoption("--logging-filter").split(","):
           # Use `logger_name.trim()[1:]` if you want the `-name` CLI syntax.
           logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name.trim())
           logger.disabled = True
   ```

   You can then call pytest in the following way:

   ```
   pytest --logging-filter matplotlib,chardet,...
   ```

The default approach by pytest is to hide all logs but provide the `caplog` fixture to inspect log output in your test cases. This is quite powerful if you are looking for specific log lines. So the question is also why you need to see those logs at all in your test suite?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a log filter to `conftest.py` looks like it might be useful and I'll come back to that at some point in the future. For now though, we've just gone for silencing the logs in the application. We don't see them at any point when the app is running, not just during testing.

```
# Hide verbose third-party logs
for log_name in ('matplotlib', 'fiona.env', 'fiona._env', 'PIL', 'chardet.charsetprober'):
    other_log = logging.getLogger(log_name)
    other_log.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pytest supports this by a command line argument (--log-disable) from version 7.3.0 onwards.

From their [docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.3.x/how-to/logging.html) :

> Specific loggers can be disabled via --log-disable={logger_name}. This
> argument can be passed multiple times:
>
> `pytest --log-disable=main --log-disable=testing`

If you are using pytest>=7.3, you could use :

`pytest --log-disable=matplotlib --log-disable=chardet.charsetprober --log-disable=PIL --log-disable=fiona.env --log-disable=Fiona._env`

If these logs are to be ignored for all test runs, you can add these options to the pytest config.

```
# pytest.ini
[pytest] 
addopts = " --log-disable=matplotlib --log-disable=chardet.charsetprober --log-disable=PIL --log-disable=fiona.env --log-disable=Fiona._env "
```