# How to suppress logging for pytest during a github action

Tags: python, github, logging, pytest, github-actions

I recently switched to logging for a python project with the goal of being able to suppress certain logs (based on level or on module) when testing the code, as there is a lot of output during testing. I am using pytest and a conftest file. I do not have a INI file. The code is built and tested automatically upon pushing to github, and the last lines of the workflow file look a bit like so (full file below):

```yaml
      - name: Test
        run: |
          export PYTHONPATH="$(pwd)"
          pytest tests/
```

I have found various ways that should work, but don't. The output on github actions is still riddled with text (20k+ lines). I have tried:

## Editing `conftest.py` to suppress output from specific modules.

In my modules and submodules, I always initialize the loggers as so:

```py
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

and I output log info like so:

```py
log.info("some logging info")
```

so the logging output is always something like

```bash
INFO:module.submodule.subsubmodule: some logging info
```

I tried suppressing loggers from specific modules similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66761145/how-to-suppress-third-party-logs-in-pytest). I've debugged `conftest.py` and verified that all loggers I would want to suppress are indeed being set to `disabled=True`. I have also tried changing the log level. Both seem to work fine when I just run the conftest file directly. The github output does not seem to care about these settings though, and still shows all output of all loggers.

Other setup specified in the conftest file runs fine - it is in fact impossible for the tests to succeed without the setup in conftest, and the tests run fine, so conftest should run fine.

## Adapting cli logging settings

I suspected github may call pytest differently compared to just the vanilla command (maybe with cli logging?), and have tried swapping out the last line of the github action file

```yaml
pytest --log-cli-level=ERROR tests/
```

No avail, the output on the github actions page is still 20k lines.

**Is there any way I can suppress logging on a level so that the github actions page does not show certain log messages? Do the log settings get overwritten somewhere?** Many thanks in advance.

Full workflow yaml file:

```yaml
name: (Python 3) install and test
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master, refactor, testing ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master, refactor, testing ]
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash -l {0}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Install Anaconda3
        run: |
          wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2020.11-Linux-x86_64.sh --quiet
          bash Anaconda3-2020.11-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p ~/conda3-isf
          source ~/conda3-isf/bin/activate
          conda info
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          source ~/conda3-isf/bin/activate
          echo "Installing dependencies."
          conda-env create --name isf-py3 --file installer/env-isf-py3.yml --quiet
          source activate isf-py3

      - name: build project
        run: |
          #### some code to build some stuff

      - name: Test
        run: |
          source ~/conda3-isf/bin/activate
          source activate isf-py3
          export PYTHONPATH="$(pwd)"
          pytest tests/
```